# How can I convert all “x”s to “y”s in filenames for a specific directory from the command line?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, command-line

I have been naming files, of out habit as a programmer working on a server command line, with underscores “`_`” rather than spaces “"—because from the command line you have to escape spaces—but that is unnecessary outside of the command line and is quickly getting old. I would like to keep everything uniform while switching to spaces.

From the “Terminal,” I’m wondering how can I convert all “x”s to “y”s in filenames for a specific directory on Mac OS X? Note that “x” means just anything and with “y” simply being a space.

I’d like to do this recursively, handling all sub-directories rather than only one folder at a time.

Comment: With y being a space? May want to clarify that. Otherwise you will get answers that break with spaces in file names, as ever so often.

Comment: just reverse [this whitespace-to-underscore solution](https://dfspspirit.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/linux-and-bash-replace-spaces-with-underscores-in-all-filenames/)

Answer (score 2):

> From the “Terminal,” I’m wondering how can I convert all “x”s to “y”s
>   in filenames for a specific directory on Mac OS X? Note that “x” means
>   just anything and with “y” simply being a space.
>
> I’d like to do this recursively, handling all sub-directories rather
>   than only one folder at a time.

Adapting the some the basic [`sed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) concept that @meatspace refers to [in his comment](https://superuser.com/questions/876709/how-can-i-convert-all-xs-to-ys-in-filenames-for-a-specific-directory#comment1167648_876709) (which is located on [this page](https://dfspspirit.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/linux-and-bash-replace-spaces-with-underscores-in-all-filenames/)) and adding [`find`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) into the mix I came up with this script:

```
find . -type d -path '*/\.*' -prune -o -not -name '.*' -type f |\
  while read FULL_ITEM_PATH
  do
    FILE_DIRNAME=$(dirname "${FULL_ITEM_PATH}");
    FILE_BASENAME=$(basename "${FULL_ITEM_PATH}");
    mv "${FILE_DIRNAME}"/"${FILE_BASENAME}" "${FILE_DIRNAME}"/"$(echo $FILE_BASENAME | sed -e 's/_/ /g')";
  done
```

That will use `find` to find all files from the current directory you are in—including child directories/files—and then search for underscores in filenames (`_`) and change them to spaces () as desired. The script ignores “dot files”/“invisible files” like `.DS_Store` via `-prune -o -not -name '.*'` and then the core logic only acts on the actual filename—not the directory name—by separating the file basename from the directory name.

I created a test directory tree on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) machine with files that contain underscores (`_`) in their names—with some nested in a child directory—like this:

```
./foo_bar
./foo_bar_two
./foo_bar_two_three
./foo_bar_two_three_bleagh.txt
./nested/foo_bar
./nested/foo_bar_two
./nested/foo_bar_two_three
./nested/foo_bar_two_three_bleagh.txt
./nested_foo/foo_bar
./nested_foo/foo_bar_two
./nested_foo/foo_bar_two_three
./nested_foo/foo_bar_two_three_bleagh.txt
```

Then I ran that script and they were all automatically changed to use spaces () as desired like this:

```
./foo bar
./foo bar two
./foo bar two three
./foo bar two three bleagh.txt
./nested/foo bar
./nested/foo bar two
./nested/foo bar two three
./nested/foo bar two three bleagh.txt
./nested_foo/foo bar
./nested_foo/foo bar two
./nested_foo/foo bar two three
./nested_foo/foo bar two three bleagh.txt
```

While the script works, if you want to do a simple “dry run” to see what files the script would act on replace the `mv` command to `echo` like this:

```
find . -type d -path '*/\.*' -prune -o -not -name '.*' -type f |\
  while read FULL_ITEM_PATH
  do
    FILE_DIRNAME=$(dirname "${FULL_ITEM_PATH}");
    FILE_BASENAME=$(basename "${FULL_ITEM_PATH}");
    echo "${FILE_DIRNAME}"/"${FILE_BASENAME}" "${FILE_DIRNAME}"/"$(echo $FILE_BASENAME | sed -e 's/_/ /g')";
  done
```

The nice thing about using `echo` to debug is you can also see exactly what is happening in the core of your script. So while I have coded this script to fit the exact needs as specified in this question, feel free to experiment with it to adapt it to newer needs/ideas if they come up.

Comment: For me, this returns errors for everything: `mv: rename ./Springhill/WPCS_Head_Start_Pre-School/WPCS_Head_Start_Pre-School_Office_Systems/.DS_Store to ./Springhill/WPCS Head Start Pre-School/WPCS Head Start Pre-School Office Systems/.DS Store: No such file or directory`

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about the lack of clarity. And thanks, cool!

Comment: I'd recommend adding `-depth` to the `find` so that you don't change higher level directory (folder) names before changing the files within them.

Answer (score 0):

When in relevant directory:

```
for f in in *; do echo mv "$f" "${f/_*_/ }"; done
```

This will list the changes to be made - remove `echo` when you want it to actually do the rename. Like everything *nix, there are a million ways to do this, but the above is pretty clear. If you do this task often, consider saving it in `bin` as a script.

Comment: The replacement expression shown will remove any substring between underscores, so `foo_bar_baz.txt` would be renamed to `foo baz.txt`, for example. Consider `${f//_/ }` to replace all underscores with spaces without otherwise modifying the filename.

Comment: I meant for it to change all file names in the directory, as in, the files in sub-directories too. Every file-name in the directory, and it's contents, recursively.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one liner? (I hope pasting my command here does not screw up the spaces)

```
for f in `find . -type f -name '*_*'` ; do echo mv "$f" "${f//_/ }"; done
```

Seems to work when I tried it.  (You need to remove that echo when ready)

Doesn't do any directory renaming. I think that's what you wanted? Recursion seems to work fine. Also handles multiple underscores correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For batch/ complex renaming tasks use **rename** command

For example to replace *space* with *_*  in all the .txt files in current folder

```
rename 's/ /_'  *.txt
```

To rename all files recursively

```
find /path/to/target -type f -exec rename 's/ /_/' '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use Perl to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

sub rename_files {
   #skip directories
   return if -d $File::Find::name;

   my $newname = $File::Find::name;
   #turn underscores into space. 
      $newname =~ s/_/ /g; 
   rename $File::Find::name, $newname;
}

find ( \&rename_files, 'path_to_change' );
```